# Adding @QuarkusTest causes docker to run when test is executed from Intellij

Tags: quarkus

I'm just trying to get a simple JUnit5 @Test to run (the most simple test possible) in my quarkus application/project from within Intellij.
I'm caught between trying to make JUnit 5 work and trying to use what appears to be a quarkus hybrid/variant of JUnit 5 (I'm sure it all makes sense but it's as clear as mud at the moment).
What I've found is that adding @QuarkusTest to my test class causes the docker build to run, which then fails with "Could not connect to Ryuk...":

Is this normal?  What exactly is adding @QuarkusTest supposed to do? I have checked the docs for the annotation, but, well, there is nothing there.
I should add - I'm not expecting docker to be loaded - this is a unit test (or at least, that's what's intended here). I'm not a testing expert, certainly not a testing-docker-with-quarkus-in-either-unit-test-or-integration-test expert.  All I want to do at this point is run a simple unit test using JUnit 5, but it seems getting to that point is quite...painful.

Thanks.

[image]

Comment: Really is quite straightforward, QuarkusTest annotation is used on test classes to mark them as test and allow to use quarkus mock and other features, what are you experience seems is due to the devServices. DevServices are a nice feature which detects that you have a kafka dependency in you pom and it is trying to start up a kafka cluster or node using your docker installation, and its failing.

Comment: This is no issue with Intellij nor other thing, just normal quarkus behaviour if you are using quarkus 2.0+ version, but without more information I cannot help you

Comment: Many thanks @karelss - I have found a link here ==> https://quarkus.io/guides/kafka-dev-services which, although it doesn't mention `@QuarkusTest`, seems useful.

Comment: You are wellcome.